# How to use readdir in php - Interpretting someone elses code

Tags: php

For the lack of a better word I'm reverse programming someone else's code in order to replace a portion of it with a more efficient block of code. Up till now I've done primarily basic programming in php so some of the stuff I haven't come across before. Including the following;

```
$handle = opendir("/directory/of/video/files/"); //not the actual directory
$filename = readdir($handle);
```

From my understanding readdir() only returns the first file in that directory. However the rest of the php code is set up as if it goes through all the files.

Is there something that I'm misunderstanding?

**Update 1** - requested by DCoder

Here's the entire code (except for the bazillion if statements) as requested. The general purpose of the program is to upload video information to a database if the video info is not already there. It would need to look at each file in the directory to check this, but it only looks at one from my understanding.

```
<html>
<body>

<?php

//opens the directory with symbolic links to the video files (automatically populated)
$handle = opendir("/home/rgood/www/hpa2013fall/");
$filename = readdir($handle);

if ($handle){
    while (false !== ($filename = readdir($handle))){
        if ($filename[0] == "v" && strlen($filename) == 25)

        //retrieves date and time information variables from filename
        $month = $filename[7] . $filename[8] . $filename[9];
        $day = $filename[10] . $filename[11];
        $hour = $filename[13] . $filename[14];
        $minute = $filename[16] . $filename[17];
        $second = $filename[19] . $filename[20];

/*a bazillion if statements to determine which file its accessed.
This is the part I'm replacing with a database that I've created 
and can easily populate using an excel vba script and importing it to mysql*/
        if ($month == "February" && $day == "4")
        {$title = "Title1"; $description = "Description1";}
    elseif //...
        //.
        //.
        //.
        else
        {$title = "No Title"; $description = "No description.";}

        //open database connection
        mysql_connect("server","user","password"); //proper connection settings in actual code

        //select database
        mysql_select_db("Database_Name"); //proper name in code

        //this mysql checks to see if the filename already exists in the database
        $ifquery = "SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Filename='$filename'";
        $ifresults = mysql_query($ifquery);
        $rows = array();

        //this loop fetches the results. if the same filename is found, it populates $rows[]
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($ifresults))
        {
            $rows[] = $row;
        }

            //adds an additional entry into the 
        if(empty($rows))
        {
            //this is a readable form of the date/time and a concatenated description
            $date = $month . ' ' . $day . ' 2013';
            $time = $hour . ':' . $minute . ':' . $second;

            //the timedec will be a decimal representation of the date/time
            //this is not an easily human-readable format, but it is easily
            //used by mysql with the sort function
            $timedec = "1" . $monthdec . $day . $hour . $minute . $second;
            //sql code to insert the file into the table
            $sql = "INSERT INTO Table(Filename,
            Title, 
            Date, 
            Description, 
            Time, 
            timedec) 
            VALUES ('$filename', 
            '$title', 
            '$date', '$description', '$time', '$timedec')";
                mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
            }
        }
    }
        closedir($handle);
}

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [RTFM](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php)

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the rest of the code...

Comment: @DCoder - I've updated the question and included the rest of the code as you've asked.

and @ hek2mgl - thanks, I've seen that page, however, it states "Returns the name of the next entry in the directory. The entries are returned in the order in which they are stored by the filesystem." which is confusing as it uses both one and all for the answer to my question.

Comment: There's another call to `readdir` in the `while()` condition, which means each iteration of the loop will fetch the next entry from the directory.

Comment: I'm guessing thats because its a "=" instead of "==", if so that explains a lot.

Comment: @DCoder : also, doesn't that mean that technically the program skips the first file?

Comment: Yes, it does. Of course, it's possible that the first file is the `.` entry representing the current directory, which is useless.

Comment: I checked and there isn't a hidden file, but there's another file there that the initial readdir must have been set up to pass over. Thanks for clarifying that for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each call to readdir get you another file.

By putting the [readdir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php) in a while(), you can read the whole folder.

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop:

```
$dh = opendir('.');
while($file = readdir($dh)) {
   do_something($file);
}
```

When there's no more files to retrieve, readdir() will return a boolean false, causing the loop to terminate.